# Compass - Detect delete

Tags: sass, compass-sass

Is there any way to use `compass watch` from the command line, but have it detect file deletions, and remove the relevant css file? At the moment I use `compass clean` before `compass watch`, but it would be nice to leave `compass watch` running and have it clean up any files that are remove without having to restart it.